# What is the maximum length for try catch block in C#

Tags: c#, .net, oop, exception, coding-style

What is the maximum length for try catch block in C# as per coding standards?

Do we need to write separate try catch , in case if it goes beyond a limit?

Then what is that limit?

Comment: If you are asking that question you really should refactor your functions to do handle only a single task.

Comment: You should only create methods that fit to the screen. It's hard to understand a method that's much larger. I think there is only a maintainability limit.

Comment: This sounds like you basically want to wrap yout entire app in a try-catch...

Comment: Aim to keep your methods to a maximum of 20 - 30 lines. That way, this question becomes irrelevant.

Comment: Plus one; I don't see anything wrong with curiosity,

Comment: @Bathsheba, I'm with you on that. I've voted to close as it's too much of an opinion-based question, but I see no reason to down-vote.

Comment: The main issue that that this is primarlily opinion based and should probably be asked on CodeReview or Programming.

Comment: @DavidPilkington No way on CodeReview! Can you see *any code* to be reviewed here?

Comment: @DavidPilkington Taken literally, it asks "what coding standards limiting the try-catch block length" are there. No opinions involved. I guess, there are none, though it's indirectly limited by method length limits and there most probably are companies imposing such limits.

Comment: @maaartinus "coding standards" implies opinion right there. There is no standard standard. Everyone has their own set or rules and stards that they or a group follow.

Comment: @DavidPilkington The other site is called [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) and if it is primarily opinion based for SO, it is very likely also primarily opinion based for Programmers.

Comment: @DavidPilkington see above. ^^^  Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: The general answer to "what is the maximum length for a block of code?" is "when it's too large to grok, it's too large to code".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar for a `try` is

*try compound-statement handler-sequence*

No limits are imposed on the number of statements you can have in *compound-statement*, or the *handler-sequence* so the language itself does not impose a limit.